# GuzzleHttp return free array

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle

I started using **GuzzleHttp** with **Laravel**, and i have created my first request but i don't get the same result as in the bash using CURL:

**This is my Guzzle Request :**

```
public static function all(){
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://api.my-endpoint-domain.io'
    ]);

    try{
        $response = $client->request('GET', '/stats', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer a2bc3699e43bdf45804701166f658a3c14ba5c',
                'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
                'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache'
            ]
        ]);

        print_r($response->getBody());


    } catch(GuzzleException $e){
        return response()->json([
            'error' => $e->getMessage()
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

**This is my result :**

```
 GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
(
    [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #12
    [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 
    [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
    [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
    [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
    [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
    [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: it's ok i had to make a cast like that (string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this `getContents()` to retrieve all the data, so you can replace your print statement by using:

```
print_r($response->getBody()->getContents());
```